# AttributeError: module 'student.models' has no attribute 'ManyToManyField'

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm using the below models:

models.py

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name    =   models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    country =   models.ManyToManyField(Country, null = True,blank=True)

class Country(models.Model):
    title   =   models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

admin.py

```
@admin.register(models.Student)
class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.ManyToManyField: {'widget': CheckboxSelectMultiple},
    }
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'student.models' has no attribute 'ManyToManyField'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You imported the wrong `models` module, instead of the <s>`from student import models`</s>, you should import `from django.db import models`.

Another problem is that you refer to a `Country` *before* it is defined. You should thus use a string literal to refer to a model that is later defined:

```
# no student.models
from django.db import models

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    #               use a string literal ↓
    country = models.ManyToManyField('Country', null=True, blank=True)

class Country(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to use `models.ManyToManyField` from `student.models`, when it should be using `django.db.models`.

Try adding this import to the top of your file:

```py
from django.db import models
```

And if the name is conflicting with your `student.models`, you can rename it to something like this:

```py
from django.db import models as django_models

# then to use you would need to change your code to this:
django_models.ManyToManyField()
```